# Business legislation regarding selling homemade cosmetics

Tags: business, legislature

My business partner and I are looking to start a UK based hair product business which is 100% plant based and made from natural ingredients. Shampoo's, conditioners etc.

All products are created from home and all ingredients are known. Samples and prototypes have gone well.

We are now almost at the stage of wanting to sell these products to the world, for example, listing on a company website or on eBay or even getting them into local stores.

**What is the legislation behind selling homemade cosmetic and beauty products?**

The products being used on skin and hair which have the potential possibility of triggering allergic reactions, adverse side effects. What do we need before we start selling and is it against the law not to follow or is it just recommended guidelines?

We are a UK based so please bare that in mind when advising.

If this needs to go into another community, please advise.

Comment: Who did your safety and allergy testing?

Comment: @DaleM Have not done anything of this nature yet, I imagine this is a legal requirement?